# How to run appium test scripts through jenkins

Tags: android, ios, jenkins, appium

I am new to testing framework for Appium and Jenkins,My question is, it is possible to run appium test scripts through jenkins? If possible please provide the links or example for that.

Thanks Advance.

Comment: https://help.testobject.com/docs/tools/appium/continuous-integration/jenkins-gradle/

Comment: yes it is possible refer - http://www.qaautomated.com/2017/01/jenkins-for-appium-and-maven-project.html

Answer (score 3):

Step 1: Install Jenkins in your system visit the Jenkins url in browser. 
In my local I access Jenkins using "http://localhost:8080"

Step 2: Tap "New Item" > "Freestyle Project" > 'OK'

Step 3: Scroll to 'Build' section > Add Build Step > 'Execute Shell' and enter the below commands:

```
#!/bin/bash --login -x
appium &
sleep 5s
```

[image]

Step 4: Click on 'Build Now'.

Step 5: Open the running job > 'Console Output' to ensure Appium server is running.

The following text should be displayed in console logs:

```
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.6.4
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
```

Step 6: All the test scripts should be placed inside 'workspace' directory of Jenkins. My scripts are in this location:
    /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/appium-android/

Step 7: I use pytest in Python, so my command is as follows:

```
cd $WORKSPACE
pytest /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/appium-android/tests/listings/test_listing_create.py
```

Ensure you have all dependencies installed in Jenkins machine, like Python, Appium python client, Appium server etc

Comment: Hi @akvenk, I am facing the same problem. I have testcases written in nodejs. Do we need to add step 7 below step 3 commands ? Where to put the path to testcase?

Comment: yes you can enter the commands needed for nodejs to run the test cases below step 3 commands. I'm not aware of nodejs folder structure.

Comment: When command'appium' execute it will start the server and no other command will execute due to this, so where are you putting the execution coomands?

Comment: you should enter 'appium &'